# becomeFirstResponder Question

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that the user enters their name into. When they tap a button, my app checks to make sure that they actually entered something. If they didn't I have an alert view come up stating so, and then below that I have this code:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

The only problem is, when the user hits the ok button on the alert view, the text field does not become selected so that the user can enter text into it, instead they have to tap it manually, which defeats the purpose of the code. It's like the alert view is preventing this from happening. What do you suggest I do? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you show your alert? Do you call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` right after the `[alert show]` ?

If so, that's the problem. You should register your controller as your alert's delegate, then call `becomeFirstResponder` when you receive the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` message.

Take a look at the [`UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html).

Comment: Ok, cool thanks. Yeah, I was skimming through an article about recognizing which button of an alert view was pressed, and I recognize the code from that. Thanks for your help!